# Pass function or formula as function parameter

Tags: programming, functions

I can write either

```
Integrate[x^2, {x,0,3}]
```

or

```
f[x_] = x^2
Integrate[f[x],{x,0,3}]
```

and get the same computation. Suppose I wanted to define a function like that for myself - that is, a function into which I can pass either a defined function (like `f[x]` in the second example) or an expression (like `x^2` in the first example), so I can do whatever I want to the function on some interval. For example, I can say

```
SetAttributes[i,HoldAll];
i[fn_,intvl_] := Block[{var = intvl[[1]], ii = Function[Evaluate[var],fn]},
                         p1 = Plot[ii[Evaluate[var]],intvl];
                         p2 = Plot[ii[Evaluate[var]]^2,intvl];
                         GraphicsRow[{p1,p2}] ];
```

Then either

```
i[x^2,{x,1,2}]
```

or

```
f[x_] = x^2
i[f[t],{t,1,2}]
```

will produce side-by-side plots of `x^2` and `x^4`.

Is this the right (or even *a* right) way to do this?

Comment: Could you please show usage of your function? What do you put in and what do you get out? Does it work as you expected? Also you start from `Integrate` which is a symbolic integration, but end up with `Table` inside your example. This is a bit confusing: are you trying to do numerical integration now with table?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: I made some changes to hopefully clarify. No, I was not trying to do numerical integration - that was just an example. I'm trying to understand a general method. See expanded example above.

Comment: I updated my answer. The very top part relates to yuor function.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To define your own function with the same properties that (e.g.) `Plot` has, there are several ingredients which I'll try to develop step by step:

Start by trying the simplest thing:

```
i0[fn_, intvl_] := Module[{},
   p1 = Plot[fn, intvl];
   p2 = Plot[fn^2, intvl];
   GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}]];

Clear[x];

i0[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: i0]

**Why `HoldAll` is needed**

But now we immediately get in trouble when we do

```
x = 1;
i0[x^2, {x, 1, 2}]
```

> Plot::itraw: Raw object 1 cannot be used as an iterator.

This never happens if you just call `Plot[x^2, {x,1,2}]`.

The reason is that Plot has attribute `Holdall`, and you correctly implemented that already:

```
SetAttributes[i, HoldAll];

i[fn_, intvl_] := Module[{},
   p1 = Plot[fn, intvl];
   p2 = Plot[fn^2, intvl];
   GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}]];

x = 1;
i[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: i0]

**Using `SyntaxInformation` and declaring local variables**

The next thing you'd want to do is to give the user some feedback when the syntax is entered incorrectly:

```
SyntaxInformation[i] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Plot", {2, 2}}, 
   "ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, OptionsPattern[]}
   };
```

This causes the variable `x` to be highlighted in turquois when it appears as the function variable, telling us visually that the global definition `x = 1` should have no effect locally. The `OptionsPattern` is in there just in case you decide to implement it later.

But how does one really ensure that the `x` is local? In the function so far, we're lucky because we pass all arguments on to `Plot` which *also* has attribute `HoldAll`, so that we don't have to worry about the global value of `x = 1` creeping in before we give control to the plotting functions.

**Where your approach fails**

Things are not so easy in general, though. This is where your construction fails, because as soon as you write `intvl[[1]]` the evaluator kicks in and replaces `x` by `1`. To see this, just try to add axis labels `x`, `y` to the second plot, and modify the first plot to show the passed-in function plus `x`:

```
i[fn_, intvl_] := Block[{var = intvl[[1]]},
   p1 = Plot[fn + var, intvl];
   p2 = Plot[fn^2, intvl, AxesLabel -> {var, "y"}];
   GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}]];

x = 1;
i[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: i not local]

The first plot should show `x^2 + x` but shows `x^2 + 1`, and the second plot has horizontal label `1` instead of `x`. This happens because I've declared the global variable `x = 1` and didn't prevent it from being used inside the function `i`. It's a somewhat artificial example, but I wanted to address the case where the independent variable really is needed by itself inside the function. When it appears as the first element of the second argument in `i`, a variable is supposed to be a dummy variable for local use only (that's how `Plot` treats it).

In the example above, I used `Block` instead of `Module` because this was supposed to mirror the code in the question. However, I will now continue to use `Module`, because `Block` should generally be avoided if you want to make sure that *only* the variables spelled out in the function body are treated as local. See [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html) for the difference.

**Wrapping arguments in `Hold` and its relatives**

So we have to really make use of the `HoldAll` attribute of our function now, to prevent the variable from being evaluated.

Here is a way to do this for the argument pattern of the above example. The main thing is that it always keeps the external variable and function wrapped in `Hold`, `HoldPattern` or `HoldForm` so it never gets evaluated.

If you look at the `Plot` commands in the function `i` below, you'll see that I'm now using local variables: `ii` is the function, and `localVar` is the independent variable. This means I needed to replace the externally given symbol (say, `x` as above) by a new locally defined symbol `localVar`. To do that, I first need to identify the external variable symbol, called `externalSymbol`, from the first entry in the range `intvl` passed to the function. I chose to do this with a replacement rule that acts on `Hold[intvl]`and returns a held pattern that can be used later to replace the external variable in the given function `fn` by using the rule `externalSymbol :> localVar`. The result is the local function `ii` which I then plot using the minimum and maximum limits from `Rest[intvl]`.

So here is how the function looks if I want it to do the same as in the last failed attempt (trying to plot `x^2 + x` when the given function is `x^2`):

```
i[fn_, intvl_] := Module[{
    ii, p1, p2,
    externalSymbol,
    localVar, min, max
    },
   externalSymbol = ReleaseHold[
     Hold[intvl] /. {x_, y__} :> HoldPattern[x]
     ];
   ii = ReleaseHold[
     Hold[fn] /. externalSymbol :> localVar];
   {min, max} = Rest[intvl];
   p1 = Plot[ii + localVar, {localVar, min, max}];
   p2 = Plot[ii^2, {localVar, min, max}, 
     AxesLabel -> {HoldForm @@ externalSymbol, "y"}];
   GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}]];

z = 1;
i[z^2, {z, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Local vars work]

So the symbol `z` that I used here has been handled properly as a local variable even though it had a global value.

**Edit: using `Unevaluated`**

In the previous example, the line

```
externalSymbol = ReleaseHold[Hold[intvl] /. {x_, y__} :> HoldPattern[x]]
```

extracts the variable name from `Hold[intvl]`, and wraps it in `HoldPattern` so that it can be fed into the next replacement rule defining `ii`. Here, `ReleaseHold` only serves to strip off the original `Hold` surrounding `intvl`, but it leaves the `HoldPattern` intact.

Once you understand the need for holding arguments this way, the next step is to simplify the complicated sequence of steps by introducing the function [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html). It's special because it temporarily "disables" the normal operation of *Mathematica*'s evaluation process which caused me to use `Hold` in the first place. So I'll now write `Unevaluated[intvl]` instead of `Hold[intvl]`, making the additional `ReleaseHold` unnecessary:

```
externalSymbol=Unevaluated[intvl]/.{x_,y__} :> HoldPattern[x];
```

Comparing this to the lengthier form above, you may ask how the result can possibly be the same, because the `ReplaceAll` operation `/.` in both cases is performed on a wrapped version of `intvl`, and the rule `{x_,y__} :> HoldPattern[x]` doesn't affect that wrapper. This is because `Unevaluated` disappears all by itself, right after it (and its contents) enter the function surrounding it. The only effect of `Unevaluated` is to prevent evaluation at the point where *Mathematica* would normally examine the arguments of the surrounding function and evaluate them. In our case, the "surrounding function" is `/.` (`ReplaceAll`).

With this, a simpler version of the function that no longer uses `ReleaseHold` would be this:

```
i[fn_, intvl_] := 
  Module[{ii, p1, p2, externalSymbol, localVar, min, max}, 
   externalSymbol = 
    Unevaluated[intvl] /. {x_, y__} :> HoldPattern[x];
   ii = Unevaluated[fn] /. externalSymbol :> localVar;
   {min, max} = Rest[intvl];
   p1 = Plot[ii + localVar, {localVar, min, max}];
   p2 = Plot[ii^2, {localVar, min, max}, 
     AxesLabel -> {HoldForm @@ externalSymbol, "y"}];
   GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}]];
```

Comment: A big +1 for the nice and detailed explanation.

Comment: @Jens: Thanks for the great explanation. I guess I should have figured out that your simple first try worked...I keep confusing myself about the difference between `x^2`, `f[x]`, and `f` when `f[x_]:=x^2`.

Comment: @Jens And, I learned a lot about holds and patterns from this answer. Great answer.

Answer (score 10):

**Simplifying your function**

Your function works fine, but I am not sure why do you need to make it so complicated. Also you introduced global variables p1, p2 - which is not a good thing to do. Bloc, HoldAll, Evaluate - all this can be omitted. What about something like this:

```
f[f_, in_] := GraphicsRow[{Plot[f, in], Plot[f^2, in]}]

f[Sin[t], {t, 2, 12}]
```

[image]

**Using pure form:**

```
i[f_, in_] := Integrate[f@in[[1]], in]

i[Sin[#^2] &, {t, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

**Using Currying**

You probably want something like this:

```
f[a_, b_][f_] := Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]
```

then defining for example

```
g[t_] := Sin[t^2]
```

you can pass the name of the function as a variable

```
f[1, 2][g]
```

> Sqrt[[Pi]/2] (-FresnelS[Sqrt[2/[Pi]]] + 
>         FresnelS[2 Sqrt[2/[Pi]]])

You of course could define it as `f[a,b,f]`, `f[f,{a,b}]` or some other ways. The construct that I suggested (called [**Currying**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)) allows you to do things like mapping of the list and similar:

```
f[1, 2] /@ {Sin, Cos, Tanh, g} // Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: This does not do what I want; perhaps I wasn't clear. I would like to be able to pass `t^2` itself as the function to be integrated, and use a range of the form `{t,1,2}` to specify both the variable and the range.

Comment: @rogerl updated

Comment: Sure, that works. And thanks. But what's wrong with my original post? It does exactly what I want in the cases I've tested, while yours does not. Is my original post incorrect, fragile, or OK?

Comment: @rogerl I think your formulation is a bit cumbersome. I posted a comment on your original question. I hope we will be able to answer if you explain more clearly what you need.