# Get unevaluated option value?

Tags: functions, options

This is kind of a follow-up to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/pass-function-or-formula-as-function-parameter).

I want to be able to define a function that takes an option, and then, inside the function, retrieve and test the *unevaluated* value of the option. For example, I'd like to be able to define the following (this is obviously a silly example, but nonetheless): a function that accepts an expression and an option, `Power`, that should be allowed the values `one` and `two`. It should plot the appropriate power (first or second) of the given expression. So one way of doing this is

```
SetAttributes[plotIt, HoldAll];
Options[plotIt] = {Power -> one};
plotIt[f_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{},
   Switch[OptionValue[Power],
    one, Plot[f, {x, 3, 5}],
    two, Plot[(f)^2, {x, 3, 5}]
    ]
   ];
```

which works just fine, except that what is being tested is the *evaluated* `one` and `two`. Thus if those are defined variables in the current environment that happen to have the same value, invocations of this function will always use the first branch of the switch statement.

I've tried various ways to extract the name of the option value, without success. And even if I do so, I'm not sure how to refer to it in the various branches of the switch statement.

Thanks.

Comment: I think `Options[plotIt] = {Power -> Left};` is meant to be `Options[plotIt] = {Power -> one};`. Anyway I would just use strings and make my life immeasurably simpler. So instead of `one` you can use `"one"`. A lot of the built in options have started using strings. [An example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompilationTarget.html).

Comment: Note that `Power` already has a meaning in *Mathematica*. It is generally best to choose symbol names which are not in use by the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the question can be answered without making any compromises if you realize that an `OptionsPattern` is ultimately just a pattern. So all you have to do is treat it as such:

```
SetAttributes[plotIt, HoldAll];
plotIt[f_, opts___] := Module[{},
   Switch[
    First@Append[
      Cases[Hold[opts],
       Rule[Power, y_] :> Hold[y], Infinity
       ],
      Hold@one
      ],
    Hold@one,
    Plot[f, {x, 3, 5}],
    Hold@two,
    Plot[(f)^2, {x, 3, 5}]
    , _, "Nothing to do"
    ]
   ];

one = 1; two = 1;
plotIt[-x, Power -> one]
```

This produces the desired plots without using strings and without using `:>` in the options. I just had to avoid using the shortcut command `OptionsPattern` and select the rule I want from the `Hold[opts]` directly using `Cases`. The `First` makes sure we use the first value if a sequence of options is given.

And of course the `HoldAll` attribute is also still used (added above for completeness).

**Edit**

The literal use of symbols like `one` in defining the default options is a separate problem, and here I would say it's best to avoid using `Options[plotIt] = {Power -> one}` because the `one` isn't protected from being replaced by its global assignment. Therefore, I would suggest to define the defaults for options *inside* the function itself.

That's what I did above, by `Append`-ing the choice `Hold[one]` to the list produced by `Cases` from the argument `opts`. So if `opts` contains *no* setting for `Power`, the appended value will automatically be found by `First`, and that's the value we will end up with for the plots.

So with this default option defined inside the function, we can also give the simpler command

```
plotIt[-x]
```

and get the result appropriate for `Power -> one`.

Comment: This has the same "problem" that the method in my answer does, in that defining `option` and using that doesn't work, because it doesn't evaluate before the pattern matching.  This is simply the nature of `HoldAll`.  One would have to use a generic pattern and do evaluation inside the function to get around this, but I do not think it is worth it or advisable.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You're right of course - but default options are very easy to handle in my approach, see the edited answer. It just doesn't use the simple `Options` setting.

Answer (score 7):

Ajajsa's advice to use strings is the simplest solution, but here's a workaround anyway. The option value is extracted wrapped in `Hold`, and the possible settings are also wrapped in `Hold` in the `Switch` expression.

```
plotIt[f_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{}, Switch[
    OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, Power, Hold],
    Hold@one, Plot[f, {x, 3, 5}],
    Hold@two, Plot[(f)^2, {x, 3, 5}]]];
```

It is necessary to use `RuleDelayed` when giving the option:

```
one = 1; two = 1;
plotIt[-x, Power :> two]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This has been [asked and answered on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5036129/618728)

There are choices to be made.  It is probably best to use `RuleDelayed` as Leonid there, and Simon here show, especially for your own functions.  If one forgets and uses `Rule` instead however behavior changes.  Pillsy shows how to make `Rule` work too:

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
Options[f] = {op1 -> None, op2 -> None};

f[___, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  OptionValue[f, Unevaluated[{opts}], op1, Hold]

f[x, y, z, op1 -> 1 + 2 + 3]
```

> ```
> Hold[1 + 2 + 3]
> ```

The problem with this, as Leonid points out, is that `Hold` attributes prevent this usage:

```
f[___, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[op2]

option = op2 -> 5;

f[x, y, z, option]
```

> ```
> None
> ```

(Without `HoldAll` the output here would be `5`.)