# Why does this function fail when a non-function version of the same code works?

Tags: function-construction

This works:

```
dogs = {{"chow", "medium", "brown"}};
dogs = Append[dogs, {"poodle", "small", "white"}];
dogs//TableForm  
  chow   medium brown  
  poodle small  white
```

but this doesn't:

```
add[name_, fields_] := (name = Append[name, fields])  
add[dogs, {"pug", "small", "tan"}]
Set::shape: Lists {{chow,medium,brown},{poodle,small,white}} and {{chow,medium,brown},{poodle,small,white},{pug,small,tan}} are not the same shape. >>
```

The problem is probably very obvious, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't assign to an argument in a function (ie pass by reference) without using `HoldFirst` so you could fix your code like so:

```
SetAttributes[add, HoldFirst]
add[name_, fields_] := (name = Append[name, fields])
```

Comment: Thanks. HoldFirst is still a little confusing for me. I wouldn't have figured this out. I should probably search on HoldFirst in SE and get a better handle on it.

Comment: Yeah I hear you ... took me a long time to even start to wrap my head around this. I found this guide invaluable for these kind of issues http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/

Comment: Smiles, is it just me that finds this scary? Isn't this exactly the type of bug propagating side effect that functional programming seeks to eliminate ? :)

Comment: @image_doctor Leonid Shifrin comments (somewhere) that Mathematica really isn't a functional programming language, but is instead a replacement rules language that looks a lot like functional language. There seem to be a lot of examples of using HoldFirst to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look at this question:
[Pass function or formula as function parameter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/pass-function-or-formula-as-function-parameter)
. The accepted answer helped me a lot with a similar problem. The basic issue is that "name" is evaluated when it is passed in.

Comment: My search fould 101 HoldFirst questions. I was just wondering where to start.  Thanks.