# Implementing a function so it accepts functions, function names and expressions as an argument

Tags: numerical-integration, functional-style

I'm trying to write a Mathematica function which takes an arbitrary expression as input. More concretely, I'm trying to write an integration function (utilizing the trapezoidal method), the input of which behaves like `NIntegrate`. For example:

```
fTest[x_, y_] :=  x + y;

fNew[y_] := NIntegrate[x^2*fTest[x, y], {x, 0, 10}];
```

Currently, I have something like:

```
NInt1D[f_] := 
  Module[{Num, eps, sum, a, X},
    Num = 10;
    eps = 10/Num;
    sum = 0;
    For[a = -Num, a <= +Num, a++,
      X = a*eps;
      sum += f[X]*eps;];
    Return[sum]];
```

Which is problematic for me, since the above `NInt1d` only takes functions as input, and not expressions, preventing me from defining my function in terms of the integral, as can be done with `NIntegrate`.

I hope this toy example makes clear my intentions. I found another post which ask this question in the context of creating a Plot function [1]. Unfortunately, the explanation was too specific, and I found it hard to understand -- I'm somewhat new to Mathematica.

[1] [Passing a function as an argument of another function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14112/passing-a-function-as-an-argument-of-another-function)

Comment: If to fix $x$ as the integration variable, would something like this do: NInt1D[f_] := Module[{Num,eps,sum, a,g, X},
   g[x_]=f;
   Num = 10;
   eps = 10/Num;
   sum = 0;
   For[a = -Num, a <= +Num, a++,
    X = a*eps;
    sum += g[X]*eps;
    ]
   Return[sum]]; ?

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8896/36508), which gives a more detailed explanation of the strategies behind implementing such a function. One important thing is that it's usually better to pass in the independent variable along with the expression, such that you're not forced to always use `X` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I studied your code for a while and it seems to me that it does not implement the trapezoid method for evaluating an integral. So even if I showed you how to make it accept both functions and expression as arguments, it would still fail to produce correct results. So, instead, I will use

```
f[x_] := x^2
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -12, 12}]
```

> `1152.`

for testing. Although this is simpler than the example you gave in your question, it should still serve to demonstrate a trapezoid method that meets your requirements.

I will not use `For` which produces ugly and inefficient code. Rather, I will use `MovingAverage` and `Total`, which provide a reasonable functoinal solution to the problem. Further, I will give two implementations, the 1st rather prolix but easy to understand; the 2nd much more concise, but it might take some study to see that it does exactly the same thing as the 1st implementation.

#### Method 1

```
Clear[nInt]
nInt[f_Symbol | f_Function] :=
   Module[{x0 = 12, nSteps, mesh, pts, eps},
     nSteps = 1000; (* should be even *)
     mesh = Subdivide[-x0, x0, nSteps];
     pts = f /@ mesh;
     eps = mesh[[nSteps/2 + 2]];
     eps Total[MovingAverage[pts, 2]] // N]
nInt[expr_, var_Symbol] :=
   Module[{x0 = 12, nSteps, mesh, pts, eps},
     nSteps = 1000; (* should be even *)
     mesh = Subdivide[-x0, x0, nSteps];
     pts = (expr /. var :> # &) /@ mesh;
     eps = mesh[[nSteps/2 + 2]];
     eps Total[MovingAverage[pts, 2]] // N]
```

What is ugly about the above code is that it violates the rule of "don't repeat code unnecessarily". Its main virtue is that it is easy to follow.

#### Method 2

```
Clear[nInt]
nInt[args__] :=
   Module[{x0 = 12, nSteps = 1000, argv, mesh, pts},
     argv = {args};
     mesh = Subdivide[-x0, x0, nSteps];
     pts =
       Switch[argv[[1]],
         _Symbol | _Function, argv[[1]] /@ mesh, 
         _, (argv[[1]] /. argv[[2]] :> # &) /@ mesh];
     mesh[[nSteps/2 + 2]] Total[MovingAverage[pts, 2] // N]]
```

#### Tests

```
nInt[f]
nInt[#^2 &] 
x =.; nInt[x^2, x]
x = 42; Block[{x}, nInt[x^2, x]]
```

When evaluated, all of the above expressions give 1152., the same value as `Integrate` gave.

Comment: Thank you m_goldberg. Your response is very educational -- I learned a bit more than I asked for, which I appreciate.