# Supply a function as an argument to another, and find its minimum

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style

I would like to minimize a function, which is supplied as an argument to another function, and report back the estimates of the values of the variables that result in its minimum. In specific, I would like:

```
y = x^2 - w^2;
fTest[f_] := Module[{w, x}, NMinimize[{f, 1 >= x >= 0, 1 >= w >= 0}, {x, w}]]
fTest[y]
```

To work the same as:

```
y = x^2 - w^2;
NMaximize[{y, 1 >= x >= 0, 1 >= w >= 0}, {x, w}]
```

I think the issue is due to the difference between local and global variables, as I seem to sometimes get the function itself returned, but unevaluated, with the following:

```
NMinimize[{-w^2 + x^2, 1 >= x$140868 >= 0, 1 >= w$140868 >= 0}, {x$140868, w$140868}]
```

Suggesting some difference between $w$ and $w\$140868$ for example.

I have seen this answer: [Pass function or formula as function parameter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/pass-function-or-formula-as-function-parameter) and have tried setting the 'HoldAll' attribute of the function itself, but to no avail. Not convinced this is the right approach either!

Does anyone know how I can get around this issue properly?

Note: I could not declare the local variables in my Module declaration, (referring hence to global variables in its body), but I find this a bit messy, and would like a cleaner way.

Best,

Ben

Comment: Remove the `Module[{w,x}, ...]` scoping construct ....

Comment: `y[x_, w_] := x^2 - w^2; fTest[f_] := NMinimize[{f[x, w], 1 >= x >= 0, 1 >= w >= 0}, {x, w}];fTest[y]`

Comment: @belisarius - thanks for your comment. However, I need to keep the Module scoping construct, as the particular function I am applying this to is quite a bit more complex in reality. Is there a workaround here? Best, Ben

Comment: But you can always remove the `{x,w}` vars from the `Module[{xxx} ,]` part. That is the easiest solution

Comment: @belisarius - ok. Thanks - that is currently what I am doing, so good to here there are no simple alternatives to referring to the global variables.

Comment: Oh, there are! "Global`x" is the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this help or not but you can try it:

```
fTest[f_, variables_] := 
 Module[variables, NMinimize[{f, 1 >= x >= 0, 1 >= w >= 0}, {x, w}]]

ans=fTest[y, {x, w}]

(*1., {x$8300 -> 0., w$8300 -> 1.}}*)
```

The easiest way I found is as follows:

```
ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString[ans], "$" :> "+0*"]]

(*{-1., {x -> 0., w -> 1.}}*)
```

Comment: that's a great idea. Thanks for that! Much appreciated. Best, Ben

Comment: Is there a way to associate the x$8300 with the global x? No worries if it's just the case of setting x=x$8300! Just wondered if there was a neater way. Best, Ben

Comment: I don't know straightforward answer but it can be done long way. if you wish I can add it in the answer.

Comment: Don't worry - it's not too important for me. Thanks again! Best, Ben

Answer (score 0):

`Module` is not necessary here, and is in fact the source of the problem:

```
fTest1[f_] := Module[{w, x}, NMinimize[{f, 1 >= x >= 0, 1 >= w >= 0}, {x, w}]]
fTest2[f_] := NMinimize[{f, 1 >= x >= 0, 1 >= w >= 0}, {x, w}]

fTest1[x^2 - w^2]
(* NMinimize::nnum errors and NMinimize[___] *)
fTest2[x^2 - w^2]
(* {-1., {x -> 0., w -> 1.}} *)
```

Basically, the `Module` localizes instances of `w` and `x` inside it: the ones in the constraints and the list of variables.  However, the instances inside `f` are not localized, since they are defined outside of the `Module`!  You can see this in the output, where the localized and non-localized forms are co-mingled.

The reason `Module` is not necessary here is that no definitions are ever associated to `x` and `w`.  NMinimize essentially does it's own localization of the variables.