# Identify the independent variable in an expression

Tags: function-construction

Suppose that you write something like this for your students. This is just the beginning of something I would like to write to help them with the formal definition of a limit, but I am puzzled by the first output.

```
formalLimit[expr_, a_, L_, ϵ_] := Module[{f},
  f[x_] := expr;
  f[2]
  ]
```

So, my first question is, when I enter

```
formalLimit[x^2, 2, 4, .1]
```

Why do I get the output $x^2$?

Once I get past this problem, my next question is, suppose a student enters an expression $\sqrt{4-t^2}$, not using my choice of $x$ as the independent variable. How can I identify their choice of independent variable in the expr_, then change it to $x$ when using `f[x_]:=expr` ?

**Update:** I'd like to thank all of my colleagues for their kind responses. Here is what I was able to do thanks to your help. Students will get a question (yes, it can be answered much more quickly using Mathematica techniques such as Reduce, etc, but I want a visual introduction to the formal definition of a limit) such as "Use a graph to find a number $\delta$ such that

$$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\qquad\text{whenever}\qquad0<|x-a|<\delta.$$

As an example, find a $\delta$ such that

$$|\sqrt{x}-1|<0.5\qquad\text{whenever}\qquad0<|x-1|<\delta$$

I've written this function:

```
formalLimit[expr_, var_, a_, L_, ϵ_] := 
  DynamicModule[{f, δ},
    f = (expr /. var -> #) &;
    Manipulate[
      δ = Min[Abs[p[[1]] - a], Abs[q[[1]] - a]];
      Show[
        Plot[f[x], {x, a - zoom, a + zoom}, 
          PlotRange -> {{a - zoom, a + zoom}, {L - 2 ϵ, L + 2 ϵ}},
          Epilog -> 
            {Arrowheads[0.02],
             Arrow[{{a, L - 2 ϵ}, {a, f[a]}, {a - 1.5 δ, L}}],
             {Red, Dashed,
               InfiniteLine[{{p[[1]], L - ϵ}, {p[[1]], L + ϵ}}],
               InfiniteLine[{{q[[1]], L - ϵ}, {q[[1]], L + ϵ}}]}},
          AxesLabel -> {ToString[var], "y"},
          PlotLabel -> "δ = " <> ToString[δ],
          AxesOrigin -> {a - 1.5 δ, L - 2 ϵ},
          Ticks -> {{p[[1]], a, q[[1]]}, {L - ϵ, L, L + ϵ}}],
        Plot[{L - ϵ, L + ϵ}, {x, a - zoom, a + zoom},
          PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, GrayLevel[0.8]],
          Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]],
     {{zoom, 3}, 0.0001, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{p, {a - 1, L - ϵ}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
     {{q, {a + 1, L + ϵ}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]]
```

Then the students can enter:

```
formalLimit[Sqrt[x], x, 1, 1, .5]
```

And they get this image, where they can use their mouse to drag the dashed vertical lines to help determine $\delta$. There is also a slider for some zooming to adjust the horizontal size of the window.

[image]

This function has only been slightly tested, so I wouldn't mind hearing warnings and suggestions.

Comment: It's an issue of scoping: the `x` in `expr` is not the same as the locally scoped pattern variable in `f[x_]`. The result from `Trace[formalLimit[x^2, 2, 4, .1]]` should help in understanding this.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The Trace command returns a bunch of stuff I don't understand, but I focused on the part `Module[{f$}, f$[x$_] := x^2`, which I think you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, it was exactly that "variable renaming" that I had meant. It shows that there is alocalized scoping of the pattern variable.

Comment: @Jens So I've been trying to figure out exactly why all the answers here are so different from the great answer you gave me to the question you referenced in your comment above.

Comment: @rogerl I guess it depends on the degree of water-proofing that's required in the problem at hand... but the reason I advocate closing this particular question as a duplicate is simply that it seems better to consolidate the fundamental ingredients under a single Q so as not to dilute the information.

Comment: Scoping issues aside, I will say I like this means of illustrating limits. Also there may be some very good approaches in [Wolfram Demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com). Okay, I think I got that mandatory advertising itch out of my system.

Comment: @Jens So you would advocate the approach in your answer to my question over the answers here in terms of generality?

Comment: Yes, I would indeed. That doesn't mean that the other answers are bad, but if you strive for generality, then the goal has to be essentially emulating the behavior of `Plot` because you're doing an enhanced (and very nice) version of `Plot`. The question [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8865/245](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8865/245) I referred to operates on much the same premise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) points out in the comments, it's a scoping problem. From the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html):

> The named formal parameters `xi` in `Function[{x1,...}, body]` are treated as local, and are renamed `xi$` when necessary to avoid confusion with actual arguments supplied to the function.

You can get around this in several ways:

1. Although I don't recommend it, you can explicitly supply `x$` as the variable in `expr`:

   ```
   formalLimit[x$^2, 2, 4, .1]
   ```

   > 4

   This will not solve your second problem.
2. A better way is to rewrite `formalLimit` to take an extra argument specifying the variable for which the limit is being taken:

   ```
   formalLimitMk2[expr_, var_, a_, L_, \[Epsilon]_] := Module[{f},
     f = (expr /. var -> Slot[]) &;
     f[2]
    ]

   formalLimitMk2[x^2, x, 2, 4, .1]
   ```

   > 4
3. If your functions will all have only one variable, you can use [`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html) to extract it:

   ```
   formalLimitMk3[expr_, a_, L_, \[Epsilon]_] := Module[{f},
     f = (expr /. First@Variables@expr -> Slot[]) &;
     f[2]
    ]

   formalLimitMk3[Sqrt[4 - t^2], x, 2, 4, .1]
   ```

   > 0

   `Variables` is described in the documentation as working for polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

Use an optional argument for the variable with a default of `x`

```
Clear[formalLimit]

formalLimit[expr_, a_, L_, ϵ_, sym : _Symbol : x] :=
 Module[{f}, f[y_] := expr /. sym -> y;
  f[2]]


formalLimit[x^2, 2, 4, .1]

(*  4  *)

formalLimit[z^2, 2, 4, .1, z]

(*  4  *)
```

Comment: That default for the formal argument `sym` is dangerous. Consider `With[{x = 42}, formalLimit[x^2, 2, 4, .1]]`; it does not return 4.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach of problem of giving students a formal limit evaluator from a different point of view. I would write a multivariate formal limit evaluator and specialize for the single variable case. Since I have a version of *Mathematica* that is later than V10.1, I would make use of the fairly new `ContainsAll` function.

```
formalLimit[expr_, x_Symbol -> val_] := formalLimit[expr, {x -> val}]
formalLimit[expr_, rules : {(_Symbol -> _) ..}] :=
  (expr /. rules) /; ContainsAll[Cases[expr, _, ∞], rules[[All, 1]]]
```

With these definitions, the following evaluations succeed.

```
formalLimit[1/x, x -> ∞]
```

> `0`

```
formalLimit[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x -> 3, y -> 4}]
```

> `5`

But these evaluations fail as they should,

```
formalLimit[Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], {x -> 3, y -> 4}]
```

> `formalLimit[Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], {x -> 3, y -> 4}]`

```
formalLimit[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x -> 3, z -> 4}]
```

> `formalLimit[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x -> 3, z -> 4}]`

```
With[{x = 42}, formalLimit[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x -> 3, y -> 4}]]
```

> `formalLimit[Sqrt[1764 + y^2], {42 -> 3, y -> 4}]`

Comment: A problem with multivariate limit handling is that you have to be clear as to what exactly is the limit you are taking. (Something like "y before z except after c"?)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. I don't think David (the OP) is really trying to take real limits, but your point it well-taken.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for any variable identifier consisting of one character

```
formalLimit[expr_, a_, L_, eps_] :=
  Block[{f, x$, p},
    p = Position[expr, s_Symbol /; StringLength@ToString@s == 1];
    f[x_] := ReplacePart[expr, p -> x$];
    f[2]]

formalLimit[Sqrt[4 - t^2], 2, 4, .1]
```

> 0

Comment: Exactly, thanks for noticing :)