# User-defined density plotting function with a functional argument: extracting variables from the function and plotting in a circular region

Tags: plotting, function-construction, argument-patterns, optional-arguments

I would like to customize the function `DensityPlot` and use it in a package as a function called `MyDensityPlot`:

The functions looks like that in a package `MyPackage.m` :

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`"];
MyDensityPlot::usage=""
Begin["Private`"]
    Options[MyDensityPlot]:=Options[DensityPlot];
        MyDensityPlot[fn_,range_,options:OptionsPattern[]] := 
          Module[{ii, p1, externalSymbol, localx,localy}, 
           externalSymbol = With[{currentContextQ=Context@#===$Context&},DeleteDuplicates@Cases[{fn},_Symbol?currentContextQ,Infinity]];
           ii = Unevaluated[fn] /. externalSymbol[[1]] :> localx/.externalSymbol[[2]]:>localy;
           p1 = DensityPlot[ii, {localx,localy} \[Element] Disk[{0,0},range],options]
        ]//Quiet;
End[];
```

I used the answer of the following question: [Pass function or formula as function parameter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/pass-function-or-formula-as-function-parameter) in order to pass the function `fn` as an argument.

Then, from this answer:
[Extracting variables from an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression), I extract, in the package context, the variable names of the function `fn` and replace them by local variables `localx` `localy` for the plot.

It's working but I think it's not a good code, in particular if the function `fn` as just one variable, `externalSymbol[[2]]` wouldn't exist :

```
MyDensityPlot[x, 1]
Part::partw: Part 2 of {x} does not exist. >>
```

But the graphic will be displayed anyway. I'm then using a `//Quiet;` at the end of the function... but it's really circumvent the problem. So if you have any suggestions to improve this function definition.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the desired outcome when the function given has a number of variables not equal to 2?  I feel like the results from all of these `{MyDensityPlot[Sin[a^2 - b], 5, PlotPoints -> 50],
 MyDensityPlot[Sin[f], 5],
 MyDensityPlot[3, 5],
 MyDensityPlot[a + b + c, 5]}` make sense.  Would you rather the function not make a plot at all if the list of variables is not equal to 2?

Comment: If the function is one variable or two, the function makes sens, but if it's three or more variable like your example `MyDensityPlot[a+b+c,5]`, the plot fails, as in `DensityPlot` built-in function. So yep, the behaviour should be as in `DensityPlot`. However `DensityPlot` doesn't generate an error when there is only one variable, and `MyDensityPlot` does, thus my question about more efficient code maybe.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to meet your requirements,

```
MyDensityPlot::argerr = "Number of undefined variables > 3";
Options[MyDensityPlot] := Options[DensityPlot];
MyDensityPlot[fn_, range_, options : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{p1, externalSymbol, localx, localy, reg},
   externalSymbol = 
    With[{currentContextQ = Context@# === $Context &},
     DeleteDuplicates@
      Cases[{fn}, _Symbol?currentContextQ, Infinity]];
   If[Length@externalSymbol > 2,
    Message[MyDensityPlot::argerr];
    $Failed,
    reg = 
     PadRight[externalSymbol, 2, {localx, localy}] \[Element] 
      Disk[{0, 0}, range];
    p1 = DensityPlot[fn, Evaluate@reg, options]
    ]
   ];
```

Here are examples using 0, 1, 2, and 3 variables, the last of which generates a user-defined error message,

```
{MyDensityPlot[Sin[a^2 - b], 5, PlotPoints -> 50, FrameStyle -> Red],
 MyDensityPlot[Sin[f], 5],
 MyDensityPlot[3, 5],
 MyDensityPlot[a + b + c, 5]}
```

> `MyDensityPlot::argerr:` Number of undefined variables > 3

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This works great ! Thank you