# Locally (de)assigning a value

Tags: core-language, scoping

I have failed in adapt the methods discussed in

$\qquad$[Pass function or formula as function parameter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/pass-function-or-formula-as-function-parameter)

to my work.

I would like to know if there is a way to say the following to Mathematica:

> If `x` (global) has been assigned a value, put this value in a new variable, clear `x` and then later reassign the first value to `x`.

Comment: `Block` combined with a localized temp variable?

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing is just a private but awkward implementation of [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html). Keep in mind, that `Block` is not a function for organizing code into lexical blocks. In Mathematica, `Module` does that. `Block` is for dynamically establishing a new scoping environment; i.e., it ***blocks*** assignments in enclosing scopes from being seen the scopes it encloses.