# Imitate Integrate's behavior with regard to the integrand parameter (scoping/naming)

Tags: function-construction, scoping, hold, arguments

Using `Integrate`, I can do any of the following:

```
Integrate[x^2, {x,0,2}]

Clear[f]; f[x_]:=x^2; Integrate[f[x],{x,0,2}]

Clear[f]; f=x^2; Integrate[f,{x,0,2}]
```

and all three return `8/3`, as they should. When I asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8865/790), the accepted answer works, as I just discovered, in the first and second cases, but not in the third. In the third case, using `HoldAll` prevents the first argument from being properly evaluated. For reference, a simplified version of the solution proposed in the above referenced question, which simply returns the given function with variable name translated to an internal local, is:

```
Clear[i]; 
i[fn_, intvl_] := 
 Module[{ii, externalSymbol, localVar}, 
  externalSymbol = 
   ReleaseHold[Hold[intvl] /. {x_, y__} :> HoldPattern[x]];
  ii = ReleaseHold[Hold[fn] /. externalSymbol :> localVar];
  ii];
SetAttributes[i, HoldAll];
```

When invoked as above (with `i` in place of `Integrate`), the three invocations return respectively `localvar$<number>^2`, `localvar$<number>^2`, `x^2`.

Is it possible to define `i` so that its parameter interpretation behavior matches that of `Integrate`?

Comment: But `Integrate` is not `HoldAll`. p.s. take a look at `table` implementation in this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/567/5478

Comment: @Kuba That's pretty interesting. So I wonder why the answer to the question I linked to above gave a much more complicated solution? The point of that original question was to isolate the variable name in the parameter list from any values that it held outside of the function. (I know that that wasn't your answer.)