# I want Mathematica to evaluate $\int(1 + \delta (x - \text {x0})) p[x] dx$ as $p[x0]+\int p[x] dx$, where $p[x]$ remains unspecified

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, symbolic

I define the simple function:

```
   Simp[h_] := Integrate[h[x] p[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

where the function `p[x]` is continuous, but I want to define later, not now.

I want to evaluate `Simp[h]` when `h` is, say, $1 + \delta$. This ought to be easy, but how do I get Mathematica to do the obvious?  My work around is to break the evaluation into two parts and add the results myself.  However, in my real problem, `Simp[h]` appears in several places inside a nonlinear functional. Now things get tedious. It doesn't help that in my real problem the DiracDelta ($\delta$) is a weighted train of unequally spaced DiracDeltas.  The DiracComb is useless for me.

Comment: Your `Simp[h]` is not a usual function,
but a functional. If you want  `Simp[h]` to handle the $\delta$-distribution, then this
 is a functional on a complex space. Ask it at a math forum, say MSE.

Comment: You might want to check out `Convolve`.

Answer (score 3):

The core problem is that `Integrate[f[x],x]` does not distribute over `f[x]`, if `f[x]` is the sum of other functions.  So, use

```
simp[h_] := Map[Integrate[# p[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] &, h]
simp[1 + DiracDelta[x]]
(* Integrate[p[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] + p[0] *)
```

The following also works, directly addressing the distribution issue.

```
simp1[h_] := Distribute[Integrate[Expand[h p[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

Comment: You nailed it.  That is what i needed.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this helps but this might be an approach to solve your problem:

```
Simp[x0_][f_] := Integrate[f[x]*DiracDelta[x - x0], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

I just used `f[x]*DiracDelta[x - x0]` instead of `f[x]*(1+DiracDelta[x - x0])`, so it is easier to see if the calculations are correct.

So at any point you can define a function, e.g.

```
g[x_] := x + 1;
```

and call the `Simp`-Function to get the desiered result:

```
Simp[2][g]
```

> 3

Does this help? For more information about this topic check out this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/pass-function-or-formula-as-function-parameter).